# Fluent NHibernate Joined-Subclass Problems

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate

I have this class

```
public class Address:Entity {
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual string Zip { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fax { get; set; }
    public virtual string TaxId { get; set; }
}
```

as a base class for

```
public class Location:Address {
    public virtual string OfficeHours { get; set; }
    public virtual string PatientAgeRestrictions { get; set; }
    public virtual bool WheelchairAccess { get; set; }
    public virtual string ContactPerson { get; set; }
}
```

Then I use this to build my schema.

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Mappings(m => {
    m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoPersistenceModel.MapEntitiesFromAssemblyOf<Provider>()
        .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Entities")
        .ConventionDiscovery.AddFromAssemblyOf<UnderscoreIdDelimiter>()
        .WithSetup(s => {
            s.IsBaseType =
                type => type == typeof(Credentialing.Data.Entity);
        })
    );
})
.ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

When I do this, the conventions for the column naming and table naming aren't being applied to my location table.  What am I missing?

Comment: When was the last time you updated the source?

Comment: I think we're on rev 488, was this a known issue?  I ended up just changing the way I was trying to do it, but leaving the question open in case I got an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be fixed as of revision 531.